# AzCopy advanced pattern matching / last x blobs

Tags: azure, azcopy, azure-blob-storage

I am working on a backup solution for our blob storage. One of the requirements is being able to do a partial backup (will be used for test environments), where I'd only take the last ~1000 blobs that were uploaded to the storage and copy to the other storage account.
Our blobs are just named as numbers 1, 2, ..., 756479,...

I currently cannot see parameter that would 'take last x blobs' in AzCopy..

I have tried to specify /Pattern parameter, but that does NOT seem to support this /Pattern: 756* 
It does not copy the blob named 756479. It only works as a prefix, without the *, which would match unwanted blobs, such as 756, 7560, 75612...

Could someone clarify whether real regex pattern matching is possible in AzCopy, or how could I solve this issue?

Comment: Do you mean the vhd names are numbers only ? U have different different containers for blobs or you are heaping all blobs under same storage ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. It's a simple blob storage, for our pdfs, excel files etc. renamed to just an integer. They are all in one container. I want to make a backup of these, to a different blob storage account with the same container name.

Answer (score 2):

No, AzCopy doesn't support regex pattern matching when source is blob, as the blob service only supports prefix blob query. And unfortunately, there isn't an option in AzCopy to specify "last" N blobs.

If you would like to implement an incremental backup mechanism, perhaps you can check whether option /XO fits your requirement:

```
Excludes an older source resource. The resource will not be copied if the source resource is older than destination.
```

For further details of AzCopy, please refer to http://aka.ms/azcopy.